# Rename the enumerate environment

Tags: macros, enumerate, enumitem

I want to rename `enumerate` to something like `enum` or even `ol` for short typing. But nothing helps me.

The correct formatting is

[image]

If I use `\newcommand{\ol}{\enumerate}`, I get wrong formatting like

[image]

If I use `\let\ol\enumerate` I get even more wrong formatting like

[image]

I think something may go wrong because I use `\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*}` from `enumitem`, but when I move renaming before or after setting margin, nothing changes.

PS: I even want to rename `\begin` to `\b`, and I get even more strange errors. Where can I read something about it?

Comment: for enumerate `\newenvironment{enum}{\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}` but I would not do that, for renaming `\begin` and `\end` don't do it, you will break many latex constructs.  Any reasonable editor should be able to add `\begin{enumerate}\end{enumerate}`  with a 2 or 3 key shortcut so there is no typing advantage to renaming and many disadvantages as people and syntax highlighters will find it harder to understand your document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I think this is more of  an editor problem; use shortcuts so that the editor displays `\begin{enumerate}`, `\end{enumerate}` and the cursor in-between.

Comment: Of course I can use (and use) shortcuts. The problem is that all that cumbersome constructions make it difficult to read the LaTeX code.

Comment: Mmm, `\let\ol\enumerate` should actually work without affecting the formatting. But you should also do `\let\endol\endenumerate`, otherwise the environment end might cause problems. Without an compilable MWE it's hard to track it down.

Comment: @wiki-fan: Then you might be interested in [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) instead.

Comment: `enumitem` lets you define new list environments, e.g. `\newlist{ol}{enumerate}{4} \setlist[ol]{label=\arabic*.}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to rename the `enumerate` environment to `ol` you need to rename its end-macro as well:

```
\let\ol\enumerate 
\let\endol\endenumerate
```

Or, in a more LaTeX style:

```
\newenvironment{enum}{\enumerate}{\endenumerate}
```